# Largest discount grouped by product category

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I'm fairly new to SQL. I'm using the Order Entry sample schema in Oracle 12c. I want to find the largest percentage discount in OE.Product_Information.list_price by product category name.

I've tried to group the categories, but somehow I end up getting duplicates of the same category with different discount prices. I understand that this might be due to the products in the category. To distinguish the categories further, I've included the year. Is there a better way to solve this?

This is what I have so far

```
     SELECT * 
FROM 
    (
      SELECT ROUND(((p.LIST_PRICE-i.UNIT_PRICE)/i.UNIT_PRICE)*100,2)AS LARGEST_DISCOUNT_PERCENT,
        t.CATEGORY_NAME
      FROM OE.PRODUCT_INFORMATION p, 
        OE.CATEGORIES_TAB t, 
        OE.ORDER_ITEMS i
      WHERE t.CATEGORY_ID = p.CATEGORY_ID 
        AND i.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID 
        AND rownum <=602
      GROUP BY 
        ROUND(((p.LIST_PRICE-i.UNIT_PRICE)/i.UNIT_PRICE)*100,2),
        t.CATEGORY_NAME)
    ORDER BY LARGEST_DISCOUNT_PERCENT DESC ;
```

Results:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxIQH.png)

edit: just to clarify this a bit further -

I'm using the oracle 12c sample schema - Order Entry. There are several tables within this schema. For what I'm trying to solve, I'm using the following tables:
- Product_Information
- Categories_Tab
- Order_Items

The Relational diagram for this schema and tables which I'm working with looks like this:
[Relational Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2A3j.png)

I wanted to know whether there was a way to consolidate the highest discounts by category where category doesn't repeat hence finding the category name that offers the largest discount from it's list price to it's unit price.

Comment: Pls share your sample input and output with schema...

Comment: I didn't input anything to the schema. The order entry schema is a set of sample schema's that are available with oracle 12c.

Comment: If you can be elaborate with your question it would be easy to get better understanding for folks visiting this question.

Comment: I added the relational diagram as well as specified which tables I'm working with in the schema. Is this slightly more helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Try below and check if you are getting the desired result.

PS: Query is not test due to lack of sample data in the question:

```
  SELECT LARGEST_DISCOUNT_PERCENT,
         CATEGORY_NAME,
         rank()over (partition by  CATEGORY_NAME ,LARGEST_DISCOUNT_PERCENT order by LARGEST_DISCOUNT_PERCENT desc) rnk  
    FROM (  SELECT ROUND ( ( (p.LIST_PRICE - i.UNIT_PRICE) / i.UNIT_PRICE) * 100,
                          2)   AS LARGEST_DISCOUNT_PERCENT,
                           t.CATEGORY_NAME CATEGORY_NAME,                            
              FROM OE.PRODUCT_INFORMATION p,
                   OE.CATEGORIES_TAB t,
                   OE.ORDER_ITEMS i
             WHERE     t.CATEGORY_ID = p.CATEGORY_ID
             AND i.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID
             AND ROWNUM <= 602
            GROUP BY ROUND (
                      ( (p.LIST_PRICE - i.UNIT_PRICE) / i.UNIT_PRICE) * 100,
                      2),
                   t.CATEGORY_NAME)
where rnk = 1;
```